# Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 – in-app update still not coming?

Tags: updates, visual-studio-2015

You can see that [Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 was made available on March 30](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx):

> March 30, 2016
>
> Today, we are happy to announce the release of Visual Studio 2015 Update 2

But unlike with Update 1, my Visual Studio 2015 is still not indicating Update 2 coming. Is manual download the only way to get the update or automated distribution will be available with some delay?

Comment: IIRC, the “in-app” update just opens a browser to download the web installer anyway.

Comment: I updated my answer, try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: The update just became available in-app. I first noticed it on April 16

Comment: Thank you very much. If you also find some source showing that this delay was planned after Update 2 (or that such a delay is typical for every Visual Studio Update), I'll also give you +1.